# Power Query; Filter to only show one combination of values

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to use Excel Power Query to filter down to only one combination of columns:

Example:

Original Table:

| Header1 | Header2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| B | C |

Desired Result:

| Header1 | Header2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |

Could be any combination of AB/BA as long as there is only one.

I've included a link to a demo workbook with the unfinished query. I've been going crazy trying multiple methods to get this to work.

[PQ Combination Transform Help](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mtqn4bobR5TiEk1iKqvfFVglw2VsiTWG/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115590516777709451247&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Can anyone lend their expertise to help get this working?

Comment: What are you trying to filter to get? Unique values in column1 where column two is what ? Or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments in code for the algorithm

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Header1", type text}, {"Header2", type text}}),

//add custom column with a concatenated **sorted** version of the original two columns
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Sort({[Header1]} & {[Header2]})),

//Remove duplicates based on the concatenated column
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What determines which of the last 2 rows is kept? I'm guessing you mean the pairs of Header1 with header2, not considering the remaining columns?

Normally if you want to create unique pairs, basically a `Composite Primary Key` -- you can use

### Table.Group

Choose group by in the UI, and select `Header1` and `Header2`. Now you have a distinct set of the pair.

### Table.Distinct

Or you can use

```
= Table.Distinct( Source, {"Header1", "Header2"} )
```